# How to bind an array controller to a NSDocument array property?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nsdocument

I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to bind an NSArrayController (in turn bound to by a table view) to an NSArray property of an NSDocument instance via a view controller.

My NSDocument subclass has a property `NSArray * pages`. I first mirrored the `pages` property in the view controller, but that means that the table view does not update when the NSDocument adds items to its `pages` array. The only ways to force an update in this case are either `will..`/`didChangeValueForKey:@"pages"` in the view controller, but that's not practical when the change is not triggered from the view controller. Calling `will/didChangeValueForKey` in the NSDocument directly does not trigger the array controller to update.

I tried to bind directly to the ViewController's `document.pages`, but that doesn't seem to work, or at least doesn't show any updates, either.

What would be the right technique to use here?

Comment: Did you check if the `pages` property follows the rules of [KVO Compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE)?

Comment: Since NSDocument is inheriting from NSObject, I assume it is KVO compliant. The pages property is deffined as `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *pages;` - from what I understand, that should be all that is required, right?

Comment: If you do `self.pages = someArray` yes, if you do `[self.pages addObject:someObject]` no. You have to use `mutableArrayValueForKey:` or `willChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`/`didChange:valuesAtIndexes:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - even though the problem was not where I was looking for it.

I was binding the Array Controller to a `document` property created like this:

```
- (Document *)document {
    return (Document *)self.view.window.windowController.document;
}
```

That does not work, because it is not KVO-compatible. The solution was to simply assign the NSDocument instance to `self.representedObject`, which is a "real" property and thus observable.

Wrapping changes to the `pages` array into `willChangeValudForKey:` / `didChangeValueForKey:` does work to update the bound Array Controller as expected, although the more specific versions Willeke suggested in his comment are probably more correct.